# PHP Mailer no me envía correo

Tags: php, sql, phpmailer

Tengo un problema rarisimo.
Resulta que estoy usando phpmailer para enviar correos en un pequeño sistema que estoy haciendo

```
<?php
require ("scriptValidaSession.php");
require ("../clases/ticket.class.php");
require ("../clases/baseDatos.class.php");
require ("../clases/usuario.class.php");
require ("../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$conexion = new baseDatos();

if ($conexion->connect_errno)
{    
    echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
}

$usuario = new Usuario();
$consulta = $usuario->searchUser($conexion, $_GET['idUser']);
$resultado = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$usuario2 = new Usuario();
$consulta2 = $usuario2->searchUser($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
$resultado2 = $consulta2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ticket = new Ticket();
$ticket->setStatus(3);
$ticket->setFecha();
$ticket->changueStatus($conexion, $_GET['id'], 0, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);

$conexion->close();

//Envio de correo electronico al usuario
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host         = "elcorreomio@gmail.com";
$mail->Port         = 465;// or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username     = "elcorreomio@gmail.com";
$mail->Password     = "micontraseña";
$mail->SetFrom("elcorreomio@gmail.com","losvendepan");
$mail->Subject      = "Ticket Cerrado #".$_GET['id'];
if($_GET['idUser'] != $_SESSION['ticket_id'])
{
    $mail->Body = "
        <div style=\"width: 800px;height: ".(150)."px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius:6px;\">

        <div style=\"width: 770px;height: 20px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 20px; color: inherit;color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;padding: 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;\">

          <strong>Su Ticket ha sido Cerrado</strong>

           <img src=\"http://www.helpdesk.diarcasa.com.ve/images/img2.png\" style=\"width: 40px;height: 25px;float: right;\">

    </div>

    <div style=\"border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 15px;background:white;\">  

      Hola <strong>".$resultado['personaNombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</strong>,<br> Su ticket con id: <strong>".$_GET['id']."</strong> ha sido cerrado por
      <strong>".$resultado2['personaNombre']." ".$resultado2['apellido']."</strong>.
    <br><br>Departamento de Sistemas

    </div>

  </div>";
}
else 
{
    $mail->Body = "

    <div style=\"width: 800px;height: ".(150)."px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius:6px;\">

    <div style=\"width: 770px;height: 20px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 20px; color: inherit;color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-color: #ddd;padding: 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;\">

          <strong>Su Ticket ha sido Cerrado</strong>

          <img src=\"http:laimagenmascool.netasdasd.jpg\" style=\"width: 40px;height: 25px;float: right;\">

    </div>

    <div style=\"border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 15px;background:white;\">  

      Hola <strong>".$resultado['personaNombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</strong>,<br> Su ticket con id: <strong>".$_GET['id']."</strong> ha sido cerrado por su persona.
    <br><br>Departamento de panaderia

    </div>

  </div>";
}
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->AddAddress($resultado['email']);
$mail->AddAddress("elcorreomio@gmail.com");
$mail->Send();

header("location: ../tickets-revisados-2");
?>
```

El código en cuestión me manda un correo bien , a elcorreomio@gmail.com cuando ejecuto un llamado a un botón. cambiando un id de un elemento de una base de datos por otro para luego mostrárselo a la gente.

Todo bien allí, al cerrar el ticket pero cuando me toca por autorizar o desautorizar , teniendo en principio el mismo código no me funciona...
me envía el correo a el correo mio pero no al del usuario yu necesito informarle de que su ticket o pedido fue autorizado o desautorizado.

El código que implemento para autorizar es el siguiente:

```
<?php
require ("scriptValidaSession.php");
require ("../clases/ticket.class.php");
require ("../clases/baseDatos.class.php");
require ("../clases/usuario.class.php");
require ("../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

$conexion = new baseDatos();

if ($conexion->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
}

$usuario = new Usuario();
$consulta = $usuario->searchUser($conexion, $_GET['idUser']);
$resultado = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$usuario2 = new Usuario();
$consulta2 = $usuario2->searchUser($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
$resultado2 = $consulta2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$ticket = new Ticket();
$ticket->setStatus(6);
$ticket->setFecha();
$ticket->changueStatus($conexion, $_GET['id'], 4, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
$conexion->close();

//Envio de correo electronico al usuario
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth     = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host         = "lo mismo que arriba";
$mail->Port         = 465;// or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username     = "lo mismo que arriba";
$mail->Password     = "lo mismo que arriba";
$mail->SetFrom("lo mismo que arriba","lo mismo que arriba");
$mail->Subject      = "Ticket Autorizado #".$_GET['id'];
$mail->Body = "

    <div style=\"width: 800px;height: ".(150)."px;border: 1px solid #ddd;border-radius:6px;\">

  <div style=\"width: 770px;height: 20px;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 20px; color: inherit;color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #ddd;padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;\">

        <strong>El pan ha sido Autorizado</strong>

         <img src=\"lo mismo que arriba\" style=\"width: 40px;height: 25px;float: right;\" >

  </div>

  <div style=\"border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 15px;background:white;\">  

    Hola <strong>".$resultado['personaNombre']." ".$resultado['apellido']."</strong>,<br> el ticket con id: <strong>".$_GET['id']."</strong> ha sido autorizado por
    <strong>".$resultado2['personaNombre']." ".$resultado2['apellido']."</strong>.
    <br><br>Departamento de panaderias

  </div>

</div>";
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->AddAddress($resultado['email']);
$mail->AddAddress("lo mismo que arriba");
$mail->Send();
header("location: ../tickets-sin-revisar-1");
?>
```

Pueden ayudarme a saber cual el error por favor

```
mi clase usuario implementada es la siguiente 

<?php

class Usuario{

//archivo base con los elementos que lo identifican en el sistema


    private $nombre;
    private $apellido;
    private $cedula;
    private $email;
    private $nombreUsuario;
    private $clave;
    private $tipo;
    private $plataforma;
    private $departamento;
    private $fecha;
    private $hora;



    function setNombre($nombre){

        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }

    function setApellido($apellido){

        $this->apellido = $apellido;
    }

    function setCedula($cedula){

        $this->cedula = $cedula;
    }

    function setEmail($email){

        $this->email = $email;
    }

    function setNombreUsuario($nombreUsuario){

        $this->nombreUsuario = $nombreUsuario;
    }

    function setClave($clave){

        $this->clave = $clave;
    }

    function setTipo($tipo){

        $this->tipo = $tipo;
    }

    function setPlataforma($plataforma){

        $this->plataforma = $plataforma;
    }

    function setDepartamento($departamento){

        $this->departamento = $departamento;
    }

    function setFecha(){

        $hora = new DateTime();
        $hora->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Manaus'));

        $this->fecha    = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->hora     = $hora->format("H:i:s");
    }

    function addUser($conexion, $id){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO persona (nombre, apellido, cedula, email) 
                                 values('".$this->nombre."', '".$this->apellido."', '".$this->cedula."', '".$this->email."')")
                                 or die("Error insertando nueva Persona: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuario (id_persona, id_departamento, nombre, clave, tipo, id_usuario_creador, hora_creacion, fecha_creacion, plataforma) 
                                 values(".mysqli_insert_id($conexion).", ".$this->departamento.", '".$this->nombreUsuario."', '".$this->clave."', '".$this->tipo."'
                                        , ".$id.", '".$this->hora."', '".$this->fecha."', ".$this->plataforma.")")
                                 or die("Error insertando nuevo Usuario: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }




//funcion usada en el menu de usuarios para listar los usuarios en el sistema


    function listUser($conexion){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }















    function listUserPersonal($conexion, $id){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              WHERE u.id = ".$id." ")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }

    function listUserForDepartament($conexion, $departamento){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              WHERE id_departamento = ".$departamento." ")) 
                                              or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }

    function searchUser($conexion, $id){

        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              WHERE u.id = ".$id." ")) or die("Error buscando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }

    function editUser($conexion, $id, $id_usuario){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE persona 
                      SET nombre ='".$this->nombre."', apellido='".$this->apellido."', cedula='".$this->cedula."',
                      email='".$this->email."' WHERE id=".$id." ") or die("Error editando Persona: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario 
                                SET 
                                tipo                    ='".$this->tipo."',
                                plataforma              = ".$this->plataforma.",
                                id_usuario_modificador  =".$id_usuario.",
                                hora_modificacion       ='".$this->hora."',
                                fecha_modificacion      ='".$this->fecha."'
                                WHERE id_persona        =".$id." ") 
                                or die("Error editando Usuario: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function deactivate($conexion, $id){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET activo = '0' WHERE id=".$id."") or die("Error Desactivando Usuario: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function active($conexion, $id){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET activo = '1' WHERE id=".$id."") or die("Error Activando Usuario: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function validaUsuario($conexion, $usuario, $clave){

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, u.nombre usuarioNombre, p.id as personaId, u.id as usuarioId
                                             FROM usuario as u
                                             JOIN persona as p
                                             ON u.id_persona = p.id
                                             JOIN departamento as d
                                             ON u.id_departamento = d.id
                                             WHERE u.nombre = '".$usuario."' AND clave = '".$clave."' ") 
                                             or die("Error Validando: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }

    function firstSession($conexion, $id){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET clave = '".$this->clave."', primer_login = '1' WHERE id = ".$id."") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function resetUser($conexion, $id){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario SET clave = 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e', primer_login = '0' WHERE id = ".$id."") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function searchEmail($conexion){

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT email FROM persona WHERE email = '".$this->email."' ");

        return $consulta->num_rows;
    }

    function randomPassword($length=6,$uc=TRUE,$n=TRUE,$sc=FALSE){

        $source = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        if($uc==1) $source .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        if($n==1) $source .= '1234567890';
        if($sc==1) $source .= '|@#~$%()=^*+[]{}-_';
        if($length>0){
            $rstr = "";
            $source = str_split($source,1);
            for($i=1; $i<=$length; $i++){
                mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
                $num = mt_rand(1,count($source));
                $rstr .= $source[$num-1];
            }

        }

        return $rstr;
    }

    function resetForEmail($conexion, $clave){

        mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuario
                                 JOIN persona
                                 on usuario.id_persona = persona.id 
                                 SET usuario.clave = '".$clave."', primer_login = '0' 
                                 WHERE persona.email = '".$this->email."'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    function searchForEmail($conexion){

        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, u.nombre usuarioNombre, p.id as personaId, u.id as usuarioId
                                             FROM usuario as u
                                             JOIN persona as p
                                             ON u.id_persona = p.id
                                             WHERE p.email = '".$this->email."' ") 
                                             or die("Error Validando: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: En el segundo caso, el que se supone te falla, probaste a ver qué hay dentro de `$resultado['email']` con un `print_r()` o `var_dump()`? De pronto viene vacío... Si ese dato en la base está bien, pero te llega vacío, te tocaría hacer un seguimiento a tu clase `usuario`.

Comment: en que parte lo agrego ? 
no soy bueno comprobando errores @quinqui

Comment: Viendo tu clase `Usuario`, y específicamente la consulta dentro del método `searchUser()`, me entra la duda de qué es lo que estás trayendo con todo ese gigante asterisco... ¿es necesario traer todas las columnas de 3 tablas? Sin conocer la estructura de dichas tablas, ¿cabría la posibilidad de que en más de una esté el campo `email`, como para que se estén pisando valores en el resultset de `$consulta`?

Comment: me recomendaron anteriormente si, hacer busquedas sin el " * " 
no, no hay otro dato que tenga ese nombre.
no creo tampoco que sea por mayusculas ,las que uso actualmente para guardar todo, o minusculas ...

Comment: Bueno. Aun así, te recomiendo hacer el seguimiento. Primero, comprueba que te llega el valor de email deseado. Eso lo puedes hacer con un `var_dump($resultado);` justo antes de iniciar la instancia de `PHPMailer`.

Comment: como puedo hacerlo ? 
tienes algun ejemplo que pueda usar? 
no lo he hecho con php , con js solo veia cosas en la consola. pero con php no se como hacer eso.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75110/discussion-between-quinqui-and-juan-ortiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logré enviar correos modificando el ssl por el tls en esta linea.
creo que es por mi hosting...
aun no estoy seguro, dejo para revision

$mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail